# Dynamically defining the database name in a Ruby Rails application

Tags: ruby-on-rails, passenger

Is there a way of setting the database name dynamically (coming originally from database.yml), ideally using part of the application pathname?

Background of the question is, I have a single source code that shall run on one and the same server multiple times but each instance of the application should have a different database.

Example, I have an auction site which works with the currency USD. Now I want to run the same auction site again (one the same server) for a second currency. For valid reasons I don't want to make the application multi-currency capable, I'ld like to keep the source code as is.

Setting up the application on the same server using sub-URL I will follow this approach:
http://www.modrails.com/documentation/Users%20guide%20Apache.html#deploying_rack_to_sub_uri

The question left is, how does each instance of the application get its own DB name, e.g. the one instance uses the database name  production_USD  and the otherone uses production_CAD

---

Edit: The solution works like a charm, thanks to the feedback received:

My folder structure on the server is

```
/var/www/auction/USD-US Dollar
/var/www/auction/CAD-Canadian Dollar
/var/www/auction/source
/var/www/logs
```

With the source folder containing the original source code and the USD and CAD being links to the source (no actual need for copying any code anywhere other than placing it into source.

Next to set the DB dynamically. The currency is determined automatically by looking
at the folder name. I put it into the application.rb as I need it to 
in an early stage because I also want different log files for the different currencies.
I am storing the log files outside of the source folder to make sure I don't loose them
when the source folder gets refreshed from the QA system

Here the code changes:

application.rb:

```
fname = File.basename(File.expand_path('../../', __FILE__))

curr = fname.split("-")
if curr[1].nil?
  CURR_SHORT = "XXX"
  CURR_LONG  = "XXX"
else
  CURR_SHORT = curr[0]
  CURR_LONG  = curr[1]
end

dbname = "myapp_#{CURR_SHORT}_#{Rails.env[0..2]}"

ActiveRecord::Base.establish_connection(
  :adapter  => "sqlite3",
  :host     => "localhost",
  :username => "myuser",
  :password => "mypass",
  :database => dbname
```

)

```
module Virex
  class Application < Rails::Application

    config.logger = ActiveSupport::BufferedLogger.new("../logs/#{Rails.env}.#{CURR_SHORT}.log")

....
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Of course, have a look at `ActiveRecord::Base.establish_connection` :

```
ActiveRecord::Base.establish_connection(
  :adapter  => "mysql",
  :host     => "localhost",
  :username => "myuser",
  :password => "mypass",
  :database => "somedatabase"
)
```

You can put this piece of code in an initializer, with the database name you want, depending on your pathname.

[Complete doc here](http://apidock.com/rails/ActiveRecord/Base/establish_connection/class)